# Force list-like indentation

Tags: lists, enumitem

Here is an MWE:

```
 \documentclass[13pt, a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{kmath}
    \usepackage{gfsartemisia}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\sub}[2]{{\color{blue}{$\text{#1}_{#2}$)}}}

\begin{document}

\sub{A}{1} Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f, g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες στο $x_0$ τότε να 
αποδείξετε ότι και η συνάρτηση $f+g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμη στο $x_0$ και ισχύει 
\[
(f + g)'(x_0) = f'(x_0) + g'(x_0)
\]

\end{document}
```

It produces the following:

[image]

As you can see I have declared a new custom command that takes two parameters.

What I want to achieve is to align the text under the text like enumitem does with a custom enumeration, though where I can replace "A" with whatever letter I want as well as "1" with whatever number I want.  See for example this code:

```
 \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
 \item Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f, g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες στο $x_0$ τότε να 
 αποδείξετε ότι και η συνάρτηση $f+g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμη στο $x_0$ και ισχύει  
 \end{enumerate}
```

It is obvious that the current output is quite ugly. Any suggestions? I wouldn't be surprised if a solution used enumitem.

**Update:** As you see from the image the text when the line changes goes below from the custom enumeration. I do not want this to happen. Instead , I want , when the lines changes , the new text to align below the text from the previous line. Something like this:

```
A1) This is some text.

    This is a new line of text.
```

What we have now is this.

```
A1) This is a text.
This is a new line of text.
```

Comment: I see two problems: `13pt` is not an option in the `book` document class, and where does one find the `kmath` package?

Comment: `kmath` is included in TeXLive. In my distribution , at least , it is included. See here for more: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/kerkis/ ... Why not 13pt is not an option in the `book` document class?

Comment: The default are 10, 11 and 12 pt. With package  `extsizes` and the class `extbook` you also can have `8, 9, 14, 17, 20`.

Comment: We are talking about the size right? Does it affect the document so much?

Comment: No. Simply you can have `13pt` as the default (except probably using `xelatex`+`fontspec`. Anyway, a good size is 11 pt, 12 pt if the font is small.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a macro `\myitem` which takes two arguments, along the following lines. Note that the hanging indentation is preserved if there's a new line (but not a new item).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{kmath,gfsartemisia,xcolor}

\newcommand{\sub}[2]{\textcolor{blue}{#1\textsubscript{#2})}}
\newcommand\myitem[2]{\item[\sub{#1}{#2}]}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\myitem{A}{1} Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f$, $g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες \dots

Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f$, $g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες \dots
\myitem{B}{7} Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f$, $g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες \dots
\item Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f$, $g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες \dots
\myitem{\selectlanguage{english}CD}{89} Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f$, $g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες \dots
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do observe, by the way, that this answer also works if you change the `itemize` environment to an `enumerate` environment.

Comment: No, this does not produce what I want.. the problem still remains.

Comment: @Tolaso - Please edit your posting to explain more clearly what you want to achieve. Please also clarify what exactly is implied by "the problem still remains". Which problem are you referring to?

Comment: First post updated. Hope I made clear what I am asking.... !!

Comment: @Tolaso - You wrote in the addendum, "I want , when the lines changes , the new text to align below the text from the previous line." Well, that's *exactly* what the code in my answer does. I'm really confused now.

Comment: For me it does not work.. :( Thanks for the reply anyway... !

Comment: @Tolaso - I've posted an update to demonstrate visually that your objective, "I want , when the lines changes , the new text to align below the text from the previous line", is indeed achieved by my code. If "it does not work" for you, I'm at a loss to say what might be going on in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using the parameters from `enumitem`, in particular the `wide=0pt` key. I had to change the fonts (not installed on my system):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   % \usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tgbonum}
    %\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
    \usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%    \usepackage{kmath}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\sub}[2]{{\color{blue}{$\text{#1}_{#2}$)}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=A\textsubscript{\arabic*}), wide=0pt, font=\color{blue}]
\item  Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f, g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες στο $x_0$ τότε να αποδείξετε ότι και η συνάρτηση $f+g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμη στο $x_0$ και ισχύει
\[ \left( f + g\right)'(x_0) = f'(x_0) + g'(x_0) \]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect that the lack of hanging indentation is the exact opposite of what the OP wants -- or, at least, what he/she *says* he/she wants. :-(

Comment: @Mico: It was not quite clear to me. Re-reading the query, I've added the `leftmargin=*` key,  with a result which hopefully should be closer to what the O.P. wants.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
    %\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{kmath}
    \usepackage{gfsartemisia}
    \usepackage{xcolor}


\newcounter{steps}
\newcommand\reset{\setcounter{steps}{0}}



\newenvironment{exercises}[1][]{\setcounter{steps}{0}\list{\bfseries\upshape\stepcounter{steps} $#1_\thesteps$}
{%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{2cm}\setlength{\leftmargin}{2.6cm}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0.5cm}\setlength{\rightmargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\parsep}{0.5ex plus0.2ex minus0.1ex}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0ex plus0.2ex minus0pt}\relax \slshape %
}}
{\endlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercises}[A]
\item Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f, g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες στο $x_0$ τότε να 
 αποδείξετε ότι και η συνάρτηση $f+g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμη στο $x_0$ και ισχύει 
 \[ \left( f + g\right)'(x_0) = f'(x_0) + g'(x_0) \]


\item Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f, g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες στο $x_0$ τότε να 
 αποδείξετε ότι και η συνάρτηση $f+g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμη στο $x_0$ και ισχύει 
 \[ \left( f + g\right)'(x_0) = f'(x_0) + g'(x_0) \]
\end{exercises}


\begin{exercises}[B]
\item Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f, g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες στο $x_0$ τότε να 
 αποδείξετε ότι και η συνάρτηση $f+g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμη στο $x_0$ και ισχύει 
 \[ \left( f + g\right)'(x_0) = f'(x_0) + g'(x_0) \]


\item Αν οι συναρτήσεις $f, g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμες στο $x_0$ τότε να 
 αποδείξετε ότι και η συνάρτηση $f+g$ είναι παραγωγίσιμη στο $x_0$ και ισχύει 
 \[ \left( f + g\right)'(x_0) = f'(x_0) + g'(x_0) \]
\end{exercises}


\end{document}
```

The `\list` command is a powerful way that is provided by LaTeX to define any list. Lists in LaTeX are a bit difficult to set as in the LaTeX kernel are defined using `\parshape` and a lot of `\everypar` trickery. However once defined they keep working well, even within other environments.

[image]

If you notice, I provided a command `\reset`. If you want your lists to have continuous numbering, then remove the `\setcounter{0}` from the definition of the environment. Then use `\reset` to zero the counter where you need them.